# Остаток от деления на 1. Выделение дробной части десятичной дроби

Tags: php, javascript, pure_js

Туплю. 
Заданы числа в виде десятичной дроби. Надо сделать с ними арифметическую операцию, после чего записать округленный ответ. Ежу понятно, что точность надо сохранять, то есть, если у нас указаны числа с двумя знаками после запятой, в общем случае, такую же точность должен принимать ответ.

1) В простом случае: как из флоата выделить дробную часть?
2) В более сложном случае: как из числа вида 3.26000 выделить дробную часть   0.26000(точность - 5 знаков)

А то я уже пытаюсь строку парсить на предмет позиции точки. *смущен*

PHP(в первую очередь), JS(тоже интересно)

P.S. нашел тока fmod. Но это же тоже изврат, не?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

php:

```
$a = 3.26000;
printf('%.5f',$a-intval($a));
```

Если количество знаков неизвестно, то, таки-да, придется применять explode() и считать длину.

js:

```
var i = 3.32000;
console.log((i-~~i).toFixed(5));
```

Comment: `$a-intval($a)` - вот это форева. ++ling. 
Количество знаков в ИСХОДНЫХ числах определено, но неизвестно. Я ж написал. Но его надо посчитать. XD

Comment: >++ling

Меня увеличили на 1? О_о  
А по поводу точности: то ли я плохо понимаю, то ли php не даст определить точность числа, будет постоянно округлять до значащей цифры.

Comment: Меня увеличили на 1? О_о// У тебя перегруженный инкремент.
php не даст// не даст. Но strlength много дешевле, чем strpos(strrev()) :)

Answer (score 0):

А если так ;):

```
$a = 0.253;
echo end(explode(".", $a));
```

Comment: Это и есть позиция точки в строке. =.=